# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<FWPasw6.Models.Rescuer>' to 'FWPasws6.Models.Rescuer'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting the error as my title. I have only learnt ASP.NET MVC for a month or so, I'm getting confused with the errors, for those who knows how to fix this error and having the time to explain what's the causes, huge thanks to you, sir!

The code i have for my ViewModel is

```
public class RescuerViewModel
{
    public Rescuer Rescuer { get; set; }
}
```

For my controller that is having the error is

```
public ActionResult New()
    {
        var rescuers = _context.Rescuers.ToList();

        var viewModel = new RescuerViewModel
        {
            Rescuer = rescuers //error here
        };

        return View("RescuerForm", viewModel);
    }
```

In the same controller which is using the same viewmodel but without having the error is

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var rescuer = _context.Rescuers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

        if (rescuer == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        var viewModel = new RescuerViewModel
        {
            Rescuer = rescuer //this works fine
        };

        return View("RescuerForm", viewModel);
    }
```

I try IEnumerable<> but it just cause a lot more errors.

Comment: As the error says, you’re trying to put a list of Rescuer objects into a field that expects a single object. In the second code snippet it works because you’re actually taking a single object and putting it there.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What should I do to solve this error? I have been thinking and searching for hours.

Comment: That depends on what you’re trying to do. If you need to pass a list to the view then create a new model class that contains a list and use that

Comment: I don’t have a list to pass, I am trying to create a form that is able to register a new rescuer

Comment: Then remove the whole view model and list and all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `rescuers` stores a collection of `Rescuer` objects. It's type is a collection type (of `Rescuer` objects). Your view model `Rescuer` property is of type `Rescuer`, which can store a single object. In your current code, you are trying to store a collection where it is supposed store a single item, hence you are getting this error.

The solution is to store a single object instead of a list in that property (or **null** since it is nullable reference type). But this is your `New` action method. So it does not make sense to assign a `Rescuer` object read from database here. If you are running into null reference because you have `Rescuer` property in your view model which you are using in your view with helper methods(ex: `TextBoxFor`) or tag helpers, you may consider initializing it to an empty object.

```
var viewModel = new RescuerViewModel();
viewModel.Rescuer = new Rescuer();
```

Another option is to do this initialization int he view model constructor.

```
public class RescuerViewModel
{
    public Rescuer Rescuer { get; set; }

    public RescuerViewModel()
    {
        Rescuer = new Rescuer();
    }
}
```

Now you can simply create an object of RescuerViewModel and pass that to your view.

```
public ActionResult New()
{
    var viewModel = new RescuerViewModel();
    return View("RescuerForm", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and details explanation. Have a good day, sir !